# How can I indicate to Typescript/PhpStorm that an object has a specific property?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm

For context: I'm using Vue, and the Vue router, and writing front-end tests. As you can see in the screenshot below, my IDE (PhpStorm) doesn't recognize that `wrapper.vm` has the `$router` property:

[image: Property '$router' does not exist on type 'Vue'.]

The code compiles successfully, it's just the IDE that thinks the property doesn't exist. So it all works, but it's annoying having this red underline.

Is there a way I can somehow indicate to Typescript/PhpStorm that this property *does* exist, regardless of what the IDE thinks?

Comment: what error can you see namely? Please attach a screenshot

Comment: Updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment rather than supply this as an answer, but I lack the reputation for it (feels weird to need more reputation to comment than to answer..)

I don't think it is PhpStorm at fault here. I expect the type definition is off, either because the version of Vue you are using has a mistake in it, or because you are defining a variable type wrongly yourself.

Ctrl + click on "vm" should bring you to the type definition of vm, check if it in fact has a property "$router" defined.